# How to search for complete words in vim?

Tags: vim

If I search for 'string'; I want to find exactly 'string' as a word; and not 'qstring', 'sostring' etc.

Here are the options in my .vimrc

```
set ic
set showmatch
set smartcase
set incsearch
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Maybe this regexp will help you: `"\<string\>"`

Comment: If i type in '\' to go into search mode; and then type in 's'; thenit tries to search for a 'space'; since \s means space right?

Comment: here is my sequence of keystrokes
1. \  (to go into search mode)
2. /s  (this tries to find a space)

Comment: No. You need to go into search mode first and then type the pattern. So try hitting the keys exactly:- /\<string\>

Comment: @shergill: you may want to look at :h \<

Comment: If you can put your cursor on the string, then * will search forward for that exact string and # searches backwards.

Answer (score 10):

Use this:

```
\<string\>
```

Answer (score -2):

Why not just search for " string "? Works for me...

Comment: Doing that assumes the words don't have punctuation attached. It also won't match words that might be at the end of a line.